# Using try exception/catch in the method definition or in the calling method?

Tags: python, oop, exception, try-catch

Which of the following snippet codes is common?

#1:

```
def foo():
    try:
        pass  # Some process
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

foo()
```

---

#2:

```
def foo():
    pass  # Some process

try:
    foo()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: I'd say it depends on `foo()` and what the `# some process` is. It could very well be though that it simply comes down to your own personal coding style.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Does difference between these parts really (in various cases)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what `foo` does, and the type of `Exception`, i'd say.

Should the caller handle it or should the method?

For instance, consider the following example:

```
def try_get_value(registry, key):
    try:
        return registry[key]
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

This function will attempt to fetch a value from a dictionary using its key. If the value is not there, it should return `None`.

The method should handle `KeyError`, because it needs to return `None` when this happens, so as to comply with its expected behavior. (*It's the method's responsability to catch this error*)

But think of other exception types, such as `TypeError` (*e.g., if the registry is not a `dict`*).

Why should our method handle that? That's the caller mess-up. He should handle that, and he should worry about that.

Besides, what can our method do if we get such `Exception`? There's no way we can handle that from this scope.

`try_get_value` has one simple task: to get a value from the registry (a default one if there is none). It's not responsible for the caller breaking the rules.

So we don't catch `TypeError` because *it's not our responsability*.

Hence, the caller's code may look like something like this:

```
try:
    value = try_get_value(reg, 'some_key')
    # Handle value
except TypeError:
    # reg is not a dict, do something about it...
```

---

***P.S.***: There may be times when our `foo` method needs to do some cleanup if there is an unexpected exit (*e.g. it has allocated some resources which would leak if not closed*).

In this case, `foo` should catch the exceptions, just so it can fix its state appropriately, but should then `raise` them back again to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first part is cleaner and more elegant. Also more logical because as an implementer of the function, you want to handle all exceptions that it might throw rather than leave it to the client or caller. Even if you'll be the only one using the method, you still want to handle exceptions inside the function as in the future you may not remember what exception it is throwing.

Comment: This is where a docstring would come in handy. It clearly documents input parameters the function accepts, it return type and the behavior or effect it will have if the documentation is followed. For more on docstrings https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/